# Is there a link between Fenestrated and Defenestrated?

Tags: meaning

Normally, when you place the "de" prefix on a word, it becomes the opposite.  This does not appear to be the case with "[fenestrated](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20fenestrated)" and "[defenestrated](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:+defenestrated)".  Why do the two words, which appear so similar, have meanings that are so different?

Google defines "fenestrated" as:

> fenestrated ˈfɛnəˌstreɪtɪd,fɪˈnɛstreɪtɪd
>
> 1. Provided with a window or windows. "the fenestrated heights of nearby buildings"
> 2. Having perforations, apertures, or transparent areas. "the capillaries have a fenestrated epithelium"

Google defines "defenestrated as:

> defenestrate diːˈfɛnɪstreɪt
>
> 1. Throw (someone) out of a window. "she had made up her mind that the woman had been defenestrated, although the official verdict had been suicide"
> 2. Remove or dismiss (someone) from a position of power or authority. "the overwhelming view is that he should be defenestrated
>      before the next election"

Comment: First post, so please tell me if I did anything incorrectly, also if there are better tags for this sort of this are welcome.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188528/why-does-defenestrate-mean-throw-someone-out-a-window-and-not-remove-a-wind

Comment: @Josh61 Ah, didn't find that in googling, probably a clone of that question, should I delete this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *de-* prefix can mean a reversal, like in *[cult deprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprogramming)*. If this were the only thing the *de-* prefix ever meant, then I'd agree that *defenestration* should mean [the act of removing windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

But *de-* can also mean "from" or "down from", like in *descend* or *deplane*.

Comment: In fact, the primary definition of Latin *de* is *down from*.

Answer (score 0):

Defenestration/to defenestrate is formed from Latin de fenestra out of the window/ down from the window. If I remember right an historical event in Prague was called the Defenestration of Prague (1618). Fenestrate is likewise derived from Latin fenestra meaning to provide with windows.